# Can I install Ubuntu Touch on Huawei Ascend Y511-U30

Tags: ubuntu-touch, huawei

can I install ubuntu touch in my android device???

Answer (score 0):

before you start to install Ubuntu Touch you should test your device.
I think this link help you.
http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/linux/how-install-ubuntu-touch-image-3531970/

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Preferably you should include the main points or even the full instructions in your answer. Try not to just link to another site in answers.